# iOS .p8 APNs is not working with Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Switching to .p8, from .p12 resulted in that firebase push notifications failed and are not delivered when they are sent from firebase console.
This hint message is shown: *Invalid APNs certificate. Check the certificate in Settings.*

When I switch back to .p12 (remove .p8) and send notification they are delivered.

Firebase versions (dependencies in project):

- FirebaseMessaging (2.0.8):

  - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.0)
  - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
- FirebaseCore (~> 4.0.13)

iOS environment configuration is debug, I am testing locally on my iPhone.
I've verified all ids and *GoogleServiceInfo.plist* configuration and can confirm that there are no issues, since with .p12 everything works as expected. Are there any advices what should I look ?

This is json payload which is sent in notification:

```
{  "to":"fcm-token",
   "notification":{  
      "body":"test",
      "title":"title1",
      "priority":"high"
   }
}
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I apologize to all. I somehow misread **Key Id** with **Key name** and didn't realize that until this morning. Also one note that .p12 should be removed from App ID in order that .p8 is working.

Comment: Please post the minimum amount of code that reproduces your issue, and you'll find SO more helpful.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath I've tested iOS side and push notifications are handled correctly. I am getting notifications when firebase is configured with .p12. But when I switch to .p8 and trigger notification there is no trace at all. So I don't get which code I can post. What do you have on mind ?